# Value of series sum question

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I need to find the result of the following series sum:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \dfrac{2}{4n^2+8n+3}$

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The decomposition into partial fractions:
$$\dfrac{2}{4n^2+8n+3}=\frac2{(2n+1)(2n+3)}=\frac A{2n+1}+\frac B{2n+3}$$
yields a telescoping series.